# Mixed partial derivatives-a counterexample

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

The well known theorem of Schwarz states that if $f \in C^k(U)$ then all partial derivatives up to $k$-th order of $f$ are equal. There is a well known example of function of class $C^2(R^2)$ such that $\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x\partial y}(0,0) \neq \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y\partial x}(0,0)$. I would like to know a most general example: where $f$ is of $n$-variables, have all derivatives up to $k$-th order and *all* mixed derivatives of $k$-th order are different for a given point in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (for example for $(0,...,0) \in \mathbb{R}^n$)

Comment: I think you want mixed partial derivatives in there

Comment: What do you mean will all derivatives being different?

Comment: Can you integrate the well-known example $k-2$ times?

Comment: My example is for $2$ variables and moreover I would like to have some visible explicit formula for this function